# Remainder/Modulus with mpf's in MPIR

Tags: c++, modulus, mpir

I am wondering what is the best possible way to check if a number is an integer (or super close to it) in MPIR. I am taking the square root of a number with `mpf_sqrt()` and then I want to check if the square root yields an integer. With java I use `.remainder()` that is used with `BigDecimal` and then see if the remainder is greater than .99999 or less than 1.000001. But I dont see a `remainder()` or modulus for mpf's. I am using Visual Studio C++. All help is appreciated!

Comment: I assume that the original number is an integer (the sqrt cannot be an integer otherwise). Then mpz_perfect_square_p can help.

Comment: thanks I am unfamiliar with that. I will look into it

Comment: Otherwise you should be using MPFR for multi-precision floats, GMP is for integers and rationals, its mpf component is only kept for legacy.